# OpenErp 6 gtk client : import a lines for purchase order

Tags: odoo

I am currently in the process of entering purchase order lines in open erp.

Unfortunately, I have many lines to add on openerp 6 gtk, so I try the option import.

First, I made an export csv with field id product, product code, quantity. but it gives me the message:

```
Following columns cannot be exported since you select import compatible.
Order lines/product_id
Order lines/product_qty
```

thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checked with *Add Field Names* instead of *import compatible* and than export file.

*product_id* is a many2one relationship. So rather export product id, export it's name.

[Here](https://doc.odoo.com/6.0/book/8/8_20_Config/8_20_Config_import_export/) is more details of import-export csv file.